# url_helper error when merging in required parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncontroller

I am trying to merge a value to the params hash, and pass the resulting hash to a url helper. (Using Rails 5)

For example. I have the following routes

**routes.rb**

```
get 'test-url/:arg_1' => 'test#test_action_1', :as => 'test_test_action_one'
get 'test-url/:arg_1/:arg_2' => 'test#test_action_2', :as => 'test_test_action_two'
```

The user visits `/test-url/value-1`, and I want to generate a link in the view to `/test-url/value-1/value-2`

**in view file**

```
link_to test_test_action_two_url(params.permit(:arg_1).merge(arg_2: 'value-2'))
```

I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"test_action_2", :arg_1=>"value-1", "arg_1"=>"value-1", "arg_2"=>"value-2", :controller=>"test"} missing required keys: [:arg_2]
```

Under the hood the `ActionController::Parameters` object is maintaining an internal hash (with_indifferent_access). After the `merge`, the hash still has indifferent_access and you can access `arg_2` using a symbol or string.

However, I'm not sure why the url generator is unable to find the `:arg_2` key...

Comment: I'm not sure why you use permit on the params hash (it's intented to be used on ActiveRecord models to set attributes). why not just: `test_test_action_two_path(arg_1: params[:arg_1], arg_2: 'value-2'}`?

Comment: In Rails 5 you can get this error `Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters! An attacker can inject malicious data into the generated URL, such as changing the host. Whitelist and sanitize passed parameters to be secure.`

Comment: If I'm passing in multiple parameters, I'd rather just do a `params.slice(x,y,z)` which throws the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionController::Parameters` uses `HashWithIndifferentAccess` which stores keys as string instead of symbols. But routing URL helpers requires the arguments to be in symbol keys. So as it is mentioned in the error, `arg_2` needs to be in symbol key.

[Why does Rails' `HashWithIndifferentAccess` store keys as strings and not symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592312/why-does-rails-hashwithindifferentaccess-store-keys-as-strings-and-not-symbol)

Try creating a new normal Hash:

```
test_test_action_two_path({arg_1: "value_1", arg_2: "value_2"})
```

Comment: But passing a params hash to a router url_helper _does_ work. It's only when you perform a merge, that it stops working. Regardless of whether or not HashWithIndifferentAccess stores keys as a `String` internally, you can still access the values with a symbol or a string.

Comment: Yes, when you access them individually, you can access them with symbols.

Comment: Do you have any idea how the url_helper accesses the values then? It would seem like a bug within `HashWithIndifferentAccess` as the name suggests it shouldn't matter how you try to access values.